# HttpParams Deprecated Solution

Tags: java, android, http

I have got one application source from `codecanyon` which I am going to build my application. I am learning android yet. I have found that in one function I am getting warning called `HttpParams deprecated`. My code is like below. Can anyone suggest me to how I can make it working fine ?

```html
public static boolean IsContestEnabled() {
        boolean result = false;


        String geturl = DataManager.SIMPLE_BASE_URL + "getContest.php";
        HttpParams param = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(param, 4000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(param, 10000);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(param);
        // Send Httpget request
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(geturl);

        try {


            HttpResponse responsePOST;
            String response = null;

            responsePOST = client.execute(get);

            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {

                // get response
                response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                result = true;

                try {

                    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(response);

                    String status = c.getString("success");

                    if (status.equals("1")) {
                        DataManager.status = status;
                    } else {
                        DataManager.status = status;
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I have tried some changes myself via `Google` and use `Stackflow` but its not working. Let me know if someone can save my day. Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to fetch a remote api to download resources (json) i suggest that you move forward to the most recent technology by using Gson and Retrofit more info can befound here : https://square.github.io/retrofit/ and let me know if you have any issue setting up the librabry

Comment: @mohammedaouledissa are you available on freelancer ?

Comment: @mohammedaouledissa In my other classes...retrofit already used...Just this class have issue...I do not know for change this to retrofit....what should I do...Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up Retrofit is easy to go with you just need an interface for your Response object in your case you need to define an interface named `PostService` and a POJO class to encapsulate your data called `Post` (in your case) like so :

```
public interface PostService {
@GET("{api end point (excluding the base url)}")
Call<List<Post>> listPosts();
}
```

Later you need to set up the Retrofit instance that will manage to call the API base URL and hook the recources you want to gather :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.baseUrl("https://{your base URL}/")
.build();

PostService mService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
```

I suggest you instanciate the retrofit object out of your activity to clean up the boilerplate. If you are adopting MVP pattern, the presenter is the greatest place where to have the retrofit object.

Now that everything is set up you should be ready to call the retrofit instance and collet the data from the api like so

```
Call<List<Post>> posts = mService.listPosts();
```

Ps : you will need Gson and OkHttp libraries found here respectively (put in gradle file) :

```
//Gson Library
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

//OkHttp3
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0'
```

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.